# Creating a system wide resource C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I am having an issue designing a software. I have a very big object(BO), let's say a map of dynamic arrays, that I need to access across various classes. Each time a class uses BO, it adds new data to it, or uses some of the data in BO to do computation.

As a newbie, I am lost on how to design such an object in C++ so that my code design and architecture is good. Making a global variable is not efficient enough, researched on Singleton but found out the rule is you can only access the object, not change it.

Anyone can point me in the right direction? what design pattern should I follow that is the most efficient and scalable?

Thanks

**Based on the answers here, is the following a correct design- it's psudo!**

```
Class BigObject {

private static BigObject instance = null;
private map;
private BigObject() { }

public static BigObject getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new BigObject();
    }
    return instance;
}

public getArray(string key) {
    return map[key];
}

public setBigObject(string key, Array value) {
    map.insert(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Create the object in the application root, most likely main, and pass it to classes/functions, which are responsible for its modification. However, when you say you have a huge object, that is also a huge red flag, which may hurt you in the future depending on what exactly this huge object does.

Comment: The data administrated by a singleton, you can both access and modify if desired. Do you need multiple threads to access and modify the very big object? Do you need to access the big object from other applications?

Comment: Why is the global variable not efficient?

Comment: @DavidPacker Is that good design?the object will be map(dict) of thirty 500x500 arrays of doubles

Comment: @JensMunk No, it's a single thread application, and I don't need to use it in other applications

Comment: Then, I would create a singleton pattern, where the single instance can be retrieved. Through this you can define functions for reading and writing data.

Comment: As long as you pass a reference or a pointer to the object and do not copy it by value, the size does not matter, because only the place of the object is copied, which is a very cheap operation.

Comment: Would something like the code I added follow the Singleton Design Pattern?

Comment: By the way, strong singletons (the type with static getInstance function) are nothing more than a global variable, which you did not like. In fact they are exactly that, a global state object. There's also a weak version of singleton, which is basically a pattern where you must ensure (usually through a factory) an object will be only ever created once and if something needs it, you need to pass down the factory to retrieve it or the object itself. If you really want to hide the global state, you should really create it in the application root and pass it down by reference/pointer.

Comment: @DavidPacker by application root, you mean the main function?

Comment: Yes. Everything begins and ends there, you could create an instance of the big object in it and other classes would take a reference to it, like @πάντα ῥεῖ suggested in his answer.

Comment: @Ashl7: Unless you have very special needs just use a Meyers' singleton. Google it.

Comment: You don't need a singleton, you just need a single instance of the collection.

Comment: @RobK And who's going to manage and inform registered listeners about changes of that collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"but found out the rule is you can only access the object, not change it."*

You probably misunderstood something there?
The only purpose of a singleton is to guarantee to have a *single instance* of a class. You can still change its state as is permitted by its class member functions.

---

Regarding the singleton implementation you have posted in your updated question you should improve it to be thread safe (following [Scott Meyer's Singleton](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf)):

```
class BigObject {
    std::map<std::string,Array> map;
    BigObject() { }

public:
    static BigObject& getInstance() {
        static BigObject instance;
        return instance;
    }

    const Array& getArray(std::string key) const {
        return map[key];
    }

    void setBigObject(string key, Array value) {
         map.insert(key, value);
    }
};
```

---

But as *Singleton* tightly couples your client code to the singleton class, you probably should declare an interface for your *`BigObject`*, take references in the classes that need to have access, and pass an instance from construction:

```
struct IBigObject {
     virtual void doCostlyCalculations() = 0;
     virtual void updateData(std::vector<int> record) = 0;
     virtual ~IBigObject() {}
};

class BigObject : public IBigObject {
     virtual void doCostlyCalculations() {
          // Implementation ...
     }
     virtual void updateData(std::vector<int> record) {
          // Implementation ...
     }
};
```

---

```
class ClientA {
     IBigObject& bo_;
public:
     ClientA(IBigObject& bo) : bo_(bo) {}
}
```

---

```
class ClientB {
     IBigObject& bo_;
public:
     ClientA(IBigObject& bo) : bo_(bo) {}
}
```

---

```
int main() {
    BigObject bo;
    ClientA ca(bo);
    ClientB cb(bo);

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Every Singleton code that I've seen online only have accessor method to get the instance of the class. What do you mean "pass an instance from construction"?

Comment: @user4581301 Worded more precisely now I hope.

Comment: @Ashl7 So, you can still change the state as soon you have the instance at hand?

Comment: @Ashl7 Expanding on  πάντα ῥεῖ's comment: You get a reference to the `BigObject` from the singleton (which is all you can do with the singleton), then manipulate the `BigObject` using its public member functions.

Comment: @Ashl7 Hope I made clearer what's meant with _pass around at construction_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for adding the code. Made it much clearer....So, is this way of accessing/modifying the the Big Object the best of to go around this issue?

Comment: You are overengineering it, you don't need an interface (or pure abstract class, considering we're in C++) if there's only one object implementing it and most likely ever will be. The object itself defines an interface (its public methods are an interface), which is sufficient.

Comment: @Ashl7 By means of building a bigger system architecture definitely yes. But I have to admit, I'm using _Singleton_ with our production software. Though that singleton provides an interface, and that's what's passed around to all the clients. I've been using the pattern simply to ensure, we have a single instance of the main system thread (running on an embedded system).

Comment: @DavidPacker _"You are overengineering it"_ In most of the cases it's the better way to go from my little experience.

Comment: You can always extract the interface when needed, but why do so unless you really need it. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)

Comment: @DavidPacker Because when it's going to need for refactoring such basic system interfaces, it really sucks to touch each and every client that uses it.

Comment: You won't have to. Just make the `BigObject` the pure abstract class, move the curent implementation to a new class, `OldBigObject` perhaps, extending (implementing) the used `BigObject` class and then create another class `NewBigObject` extending (implementing) the same class. Modern refactoring tools also offer the possibility to rename a class throughout the whole project in a matter of minutes (that is counting the time the programmers needs to check that everything went well). I am all for SOLID, but don't introduce stuff that you don't need, nobody pays for that.

Comment: @DavidPacker Well, that's simply not how I'm approaching to design system architectures, could we agree on that? (And of course I'm being paid for doing that)

Comment: @DavidPacker What you propose also doesn't work well with `BigOject::getInstance()` splattered all over your client code.

Comment: I am all against strong singleton, read the discussion under the question. ☺

Comment: @DavidPacker Well, I see. A way to improve this whole thing would be you provide the _Factory Pattern_ aspect, explaining ownership and `std::unique_ptr` vs `std::shared_ptr` and all of that stuff writing another answer.

Comment: Is your implementation of IBigObject and BigObject (second set of codes) a singleton class? I feel like it's just a normal class, and follows what @DavidPacker said: "If you really want to hide the global state, you should really create it in the application root and pass it down by reference/pointer."!!

Comment: @Ashl7 No it's not a _Singleton_ class. It was exactly the point to avoid it there.